# How to change the distance between categorical ticks in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `coord_flip()` to make a forest plot.

```
df <- data.frame(f1=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("m","w")),          
   f2=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("young","old")),
             boxthis1=rnorm(100), boxthis2=rnorm(100), boxthis3=rnorm(100))

ggplot(aes(ymin = boxthis1, y=boxthis2,ymax=boxthis3, x = f1), data = df) + 
   geom_pointrange(size=0.5) +coord_flip()
```

How can I make it so that there is more distance between the two plots/ axis labels on the VERTICAL axis?

Comment: between what two plots? You only have one plot and one axis...I may be wrong but I think you're looking for a way to resize your plot such that the two lines are closer to one another? if so your question should be about resizing the dimensions of a plot....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use `scale_x_discrete(expand = ...)`.

```
ggplot(aes(ymin = boxthis1, y=boxthis2,ymax=boxthis3, x = f1), data = df) + 
  geom_pointrange(size=0.5) +coord_flip() + scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.2, 0.2))
```

[image][image]

Comment: Not sure why this works as it will only expand the space at the end of the axis. I tried myself and doesn't increase space between ticks. Not sure why